# Delete tableview column at index

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I'd need to remove all columns from a table except the first two. 
I am Iterating over the table columns and am stuck at the part where I have to delete the column based on the index.

So far I have this:

```
int x;
for (x = 2; x < [table numberOfColumns]; x++) {
    [table removetablecolumn:([table column:x])]

}
```

Comment: Could you show your real code? `removetablecommun`, does not exist. I know `removeTableColumn`, but not your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should go this way:

```
for (NSInteger tcIndex = self.tableView.tableColumns.count-1; tcIndex >= 2; tcIndex--){
    [self.tableView removeTableColumn:[self.tableView tableColumns][tcIndex]];
}
```

You need to count total columns in the tableview and then remove them.

What you are doing is that iterating through number of rows, which is incorrect.

Comment: Update: sorry, it is deleting every second column, any idea why? i need only the first two to stay, all the rest to go.

Comment: @user2452250 Just initialize `tcIndex` to 2 instead of 0.